# Floating Bottom Navigation Menu using Scaffold Composable

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview, scaffold, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I have a requirement, where my bottom menu must be placed on top of the content. The bottom menu background should be transparent, and content should be visible below that. I want to achieve overlay kind of effect where bottom menu is drawn on top of the content. But problem is currently I am using Scaffold composable. With Scaffold, bottom menu is drawn below the content, and it sticks to the bottom. I want to achieve the overlay effect using scaffold to have minimal code changes. Is it possible to achieve using scaffold?